# How to clean up a string excluding certain characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to clean up the below string but only get rid of the `\n`, `\r` and `extra spaces` but not the apostrophe`(')` and other characters like dash`(-)` and colon`(:)`.

Right now I am using this code but it gets rid of all special characters.

```
string = "\n\n\r\n            Scott Hibb's Amazing Whisky Grilled Baby Back Ribs\r\n                \n\n\n\n"
rx = re.compile('\W+')
string = rx.sub(' ', string).strip()
print(string)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is great but if you would like a slightly more general solution that allows you to specify the explicit set of characters that you still want to remove, add a lambda function to the filter, something like this.

```
>>> y = "\n\n\r\n       Scott Hibb's       Amazing    Whisky Grilled Baby Back Ribs\r\n                \n\n\n\n"
>>> ' '.join(filter(lambda x: x not in ['\n', '\r'], y).strip().split())
"Scott Hibb's Amazing Whisky Grilled Baby Back Ribs"
```

Please note that for your example, explicitly specifying the `\n` and `\r` in the lambda is overkill because strip() treats `\n` and `\r` as whitespace but if you wanted to remove other characters, then this a reasonable approach. For example this is how you would strip extra white space characters, remove the `\n` and `\r`, and remove all standard vowels (a, e, i, o, u).

```
>>> y = "\n\n\r\n       Scott Hibb's       Amazing    Whisky Grilled Baby Back Ribs\r\n                \n\n\n\n"
>>> ' '.join(filter(lambda x: x.lower() not in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '\r'], y).strip().split())
"Sctt Hbb's mzng Whsky Grlld Bby Bck Rbs"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter()` and `strip()` to remove `\n`, `\t`, `\r` and `extra whitespaces` while preserving rest of the characters, something like this :

```
string = "\n\n\r\n       Scott Hibb's       Amazing    Whisky Grilled Baby Back Ribs\r\n                \n\n\n\n"
print(' '.join(filter(None, string.strip().split())))
```

This will result in :

```
Scott Hibb's Amazing Whisky Grilled Baby Back Ribs
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class, like `[abc]` matches a, b, or c